# Non-CDN hosted jQuery caused some strange behaviour

Tags: jquery

I was using JQuery in this download link, and included it in the head tag of a HTML web page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

In a php web page, I got these few lines of codes:

```
 $.ajax({
      url: 'http://mywebsite.com/site1/toavail/',
      type: "post",
      success: function(data) { 
      // some more code here
      }
   });
```

When I tested the HTML page in IE 6, and 7, I saw the same warning message:
"permission denied"
When I tested it in Firefox 3, nothing was returned from the server web page.

Later, I changed the JQuery source link to be:

```
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js
```

I refreshed the web page, and I could saw the returned value then.

Comment: Sounds like you had a typo in your first version of the url.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use Google's copy? http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js - leave the version as `1` to get the latest version.

Comment: @fudgey - I wouldn't use `/1/` under *any* circumstances, `/1.4/` yes, but not `/1/`.  Upgrading major dot releases can still break your site, putting `/1/` is *asking* for trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js it's simply returning jQuery 1.4.2. Maybe there was a glitch earlier? I don't see how it would cause any problems, otherwise.